# How to use animation to animate seekbar

Tags: android, animation, seekbar

I am new to android. I am trying to animate the horizontal seekbar but couldn't do so far.
I just want an animation where seekbar shows the progress in some duration say 1 min.
Can somebody suggest/give ideas/code snippet on how shall I animate the standard seekbar?

What kind of animation like objectanimator or valueAnimation shall I use?
Do I need to define a run method (Not sure! ) to animate the thumb to go next position?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

One way of doing it is by using a ValueAnimator:

```
final SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,seekBar.getMax());
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int animProgress = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            seekBar.setProgress(animProgress);
        }
    });
```

Another way could be(havent test this):

```
final SeekBar seekBar =  findViewById(R.id.seekBar); 
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(seekBar, "progress", 0,seekBar.getMax());
anim.setDuration(10000);
anim.start();
```

Comment: Note that both suggested methods require Honeycomb (API 11, aka 3.0) or later.

Comment: when attempting to use the second option the Seekbar was unresponsive on the view looking at the logs, I was given the warning error _"Method setProgress() with type float not found on target class android.widget.seekbar."_ This is because the way the current syntax is set up `ObjectAnimator` expect the SeekBar instance to have a `setProgress(float val)` method but I guess SeekBar only has a `setProgress(int val)` method. to get this working use `ObjectAnimator.ofInt` instead of `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat` when dealing with SeekBars

Comment: @MarquisBlount man, thank you , I got the issue "Method setProgress() with type float not found on target class X."  and your comment was helpful :)

Comment: @MarquisBlount lol, my solution was not for long time, now getting "Method setProgress() with type int not found on target "

Comment: @Al-Mothafar its difficult to give a definite answer without seeing your code. I don't know if you're going with option 1 or 2

Comment: @MarquisBlount I tried the second option, and used the ofInt method, like this : final ObjectAnimator progressBarAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "animateProgress", start, end) , while this is the class extends ProgressBar .

Comment: @Al-Mothafar ah I think I see what is going on here. In short you are missing the method "setProgress(int progress)" in your class that is extending ProgressBar!. I think you need to override that method in your class that is extending ProgressBar. So you can just call super inside your override method of setProgress(int progress). let me know if this works and then i'll explain why this is the case

Comment: @MarquisBlount thanks for your reply, but actually I'm already overriding the setProgress(int) , and its calling super.setProgress and invalidate() to force update the view this for animation things.