# Animate smooth slide of view from its current position to a position X pixels left

Tags: java, android, animation

I want to perform a translate animation of a view from its current position onscreen to a point X pixels left in a smooth scroll. I tried to do this in the following way:

```
oldPosition = view.getLeft();
newPosition = oldPosition - secondview.getwidth();

TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, newPosition,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0);
            translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);

translateAnimation.reset();
view.clearAnimation();
view.setAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

But the end result is not a smooth scroll from the old position to the new one, but rather looks as though the view scrolls offscreen and then redraws. How can I create a smooth scrolling from the correct start position to the correct end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) (or ValueAnimator)…

For example [this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10866148/1720332) should give you a good start.